# I had reputation automagically appear on a Stack Exchange site

Tags: support, reputation

I have 130 unexplained reputation that just appeared this evening on Programmers.SE that I cannot account for.

My reputation was at 444 prior to the change in reputation policy to do more frequent recalculations, and was at 398 yesterday prior to me deleting an answer with a +16 net rep score and casting a downvote. This put my reputation at 381. Right now, I am at 511, and I have received no upvotes nor have I had any undeleted content. The only obvious thing in my reputation trail that I can see is a +40 for an answer to the question "[A question to Interviewers: Should I stick to C++ or learn something new](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/96437/a-question-to-interviewers-should-i-stick-to-c-or-learn-something-new/96441#96441)?," which is now apparently deleted and I do not see a corresponding -40 for it elsewhere in the history. The other 90 points, I still cannot track down. It is also hard to go by vote counts on answers, as quite a few went CW, some after at least some reputation had been accrued.

Is there yet another change to the reputation algorithm that could explain this?

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/, perhaps?

Comment: Wait, you're complaining about having too *much* rep?

Comment: @Tim, possibly. I see "First, if you’ve contributed something worthwhile to the site, you should keep the reputation for that even if it eventually gets deleted. “Worthwhile” here is defined as,: A score of 3 or greater, Visible on the site for at least 60 days." I don't like it. If the content is deleted, it's deleted. I deserve no rep for that. :/

Comment: Right, because it was deleted and all that hard work put in to an answer just goes away with it. It's like you never spent the time on it at all!

Comment: @Marco, I wouldn't exactly consider my contributions to Programmers *hard work*.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram Then maybe you actually don't deserve that rep :)

Comment: I can understand where you're coming from, but consider that you did put in some time to share your insight on an issue, presumably in the good faith that it would help the OP. As we've seen lately, deletion can be...subjective. Consequently, erring on the side of caution and not punishing users in these cases seems sane. If you still feel like you should part ways with the reputation, you can always offer up bounties to other answers you feel *do* deserve credit; with these changes, the choice is now left in your hands.

Comment: Almost had to downvote you for usage of the term 'automagically.'  Almost.

Comment: @JayRiggs, but... that's how it happened. Well, the only other plausible explanation was unicorns.

Comment: It's a special reward for posting things that were so off topic that they got deleted.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, there was [another change](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/):

> First, if you’ve contributed something worthwhile to the site, you should keep the reputation for that even if it eventually gets deleted. “Worthwhile” here is defined as,

> - A score of 3 or greater

- Visible on the site for at least 60 days

The above was not true when [the pseudo-realtime reputation changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes) first rolled out. Any reputation you lost due to old posts meeting these criteria being deleted (two in your case, garnering a total of 130 reputation points) has now been restored (I just got back ~1,000 rep on Programmers myself).

Comment: Yeah, I found the other +90, it was split over two voting days. [Practicality of recursion in business applications](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/32970/practicality-of-recursion-in-business-applications/32972#32972) (not that I have enough rep to see it).